# Allow a Wizard to run only from an existing project

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

I am doing an Import Wizard for an Eclipse plugin.

It should be allowed only if the selection is an IProject and display an error (and close itself) otherwise.

Do you how this is feasible?

I tried using `getShell().close()` and `getContainer().getShell().close()` from my `OwnWizard.init(...)` method if the selection is not an `IProject`, but I get a `NullPointerException` regarding `getShell()`  (it appears it's not yet valid).

I tried with this snippet:

```
public class GetPackWizard extends Wizard implements IImportWizard {
private IProject project = null;
// ...
@Override
public void addPages() {
    logger.trace("Adding pages.");
    addPage(new SelectPackagesWizardPage(project));
    versionsPage = new SelectVersionsWizardPage(project);
    addPage(versionsPage);
}

//...
@Override
public void init(IWorkbench workbench, IStructuredSelection selection) {
    project = null;
    if (selection.size() > 0) {
        Object obj = selection.getFirstElement();
        if (obj instanceof IResource) {
            IResource resource = (IResource)obj;
                if (obj instanceof IProject)
                    project = (IProject)obj;
                else
                    project = resource.getProject();
        }
    }

    if (project == null) {
        MessageDialog.openError(
            getShell(),
            "GetPack Wizard", 
            "You must run this wizard from a project."
        );
        performCancel();
    }
}
```

Though the Wizard closes, the `addPages()` method is still called, thus leading to some `NullPointerException` (since the `project` field is null).

Is there a way I can prevent that from happening? It could be great if I don't have to reimplement the `createControls()` Wizard method :)

Thanks for your help,

Best regards,

Greg*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are talking about closing the `shell` and etc, therefore I am assuming that you have already figured out ***selection is an IProject and display an error***.

*Closing the Wizard:*

<strike>All the standard wizard implements the abstract `org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard`. If you want to close it then simply call its `performCancel()` method.</strike> (I did not know you are calling `getShell().close()` in `init()`)

---

**Update:**

The reason is simple. When you select a particular wizard in the `import` wizard and press next then the following method is called from the `org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardSelectionPage`

```
public IWizardPage getNextPage() 
{
    if (selectedNode == null) {
        return null;
    }

    boolean isCreated = selectedNode.isContentCreated();

    IWizard wizard = selectedNode.getWizard(); // THIS WILL CALL THE INIT

    if (wizard == null) {
        setSelectedNode(null);
        return null;
    }

    if (!isCreated) {
        // Allow the wizard to create its pages
        wizard.addPages();              // THIS IS ADDING THE EXTRA PAGES
    }

    return wizard.getStartingPage();
}
```

As you can see the `IselectedNode.getWizard();` statement comes earlier than `wizard.addPages();` therefore even though you have identified that the selection is not `IProject` and called `performCancel()` (which won't have any effect as dialog-content-area itself is not created) it will still go on to `wizard.addPages();`.

As you have already noticed that `getShell()` in the `init()` method will return **`null`**. To solve this issue (unfortunately) you have to override the `public void createPageControls(Composite pageContainer)`, **but** don't worry the change required is minimal:

```
public void createPageControls(Composite pageContainer) {
    if(flag){
        getShell().close();
        return;
    }
    super.createPageControls(pageContainer);
}
```

For reference see the full code below:

```
public class MyImportWizard extends Wizard implements IImportWizard {

    private IProject project = null;

    private boolean flag = false;

    public void addPages() {
        if(!flag)
            System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    public void createPageControls(Composite pageContainer) {
        if(flag){
            getShell().close();
            return;
        }
        super.createPageControls(pageContainer);
    }

    public void init(IWorkbench workbench, IStructuredSelection selection) 
    {
        project = null;
        if (selection.size() > 0) {
            Object obj = selection.getFirstElement();
            if (obj instanceof IResource) {
                IResource resource = (IResource)obj;
                if (obj instanceof IProject)
                    project = (IProject)obj;
                else
                    project = resource.getProject();
            }
        }

        if (project == null) {
            MessageDialog.openError(
                    getShell(),
                    "GetPack Wizard", 
                    "You must run this wizard from a project."
            );
            flag = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performFinish() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Give it a try, meanwhile I will see whether it can be done in a more sophisticated manner.

Comment: Yes I do :) I've added some details about this.

Comment: Thanks it worked great :)
Actually I even don't use the `flag`, since it's `true` when `project != null`.

Comment: @Greg: nice to hear that. yup... i noticed `project != null` after updating my answer :) ...

Comment: It helped me too, although i used it in a different manner. The decision that the wizard cannot be started comes from constructor of a page. So I let the constructor throw an exception, catch it and set a flag. `try { packageNamesPage = new PagePackageNames(selection); } catch (Exception e) { MessageDialog.openError(getShell(), "Error", "No Java-Projects found"); closeFlag = true; }` But there is a problem. If I click "next" the second time, the message won't come anymore. Is there a possibility to fix it?

Comment: @ Danylo Esterman - I am sorry but I no longer work with SWT/Eclipse plugin development. Your best option is to pose this as a fresh question on SO. There are many good people around.